# How to include simple javascript file as node dependency in Cloud Functions for Firebase when using Kotlin multiplatform?

Tags: node.js, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to include a javascript file as module dependency. It's generated by Kotlin multiplatform, and it's called `common-js.js`. This is part of my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "common-js": "file:common-js"
}
```

I put this file into `node_modules/common-js.js` and it works with `firebase serve` with no problems.

However when I run `firebase deploy`, the deploy fails with:

```
Build failed: exit status 254
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /workspace/common-js
```

How to achieve this with Cloud Functions? I tried putting it to other directories than `node_modules` but it doesn't work even locally.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Functions currently doesn't support the deployment of a fully-materialized `node_modules` folder.  What it will do, during deployment, is install all the modules in your package.json with the assumption that npm can find them in the npm registry.

If you want to upload code from your machine to Cloud Functions, you'll have to include that along with all your other source code.

If you want deploy code that can be obtained through some other public source (like a GitHub repo), you should install that using npm like this:

```
npm install https://github.com/your-name/your-repo.git
```

If your code can't be downloaded publicly, it needs to be included with your source.

Comment: Thanks Doug. My situation is that the dependency (common-js.js) is generated during the build process by Kotlin Multiplatform, so it's not available publicly. Also the index.js file is generated from Kotlin and it loads the common module with `require('common-js')` which expects a node module. So the question is how to bundle the common-js.js file with the source so it behaves like a node module?

Answer (score 1):

As Doug mentioned here, Firebase Functions doesn't support upload of `node_modules`. I need to upload it with other sources, but I didn't find a way how to create a node module outside `node_modules` directory. I solved it by modifying the generated `index.js` file with a gradle task which just loads a JS file, not a node module. Here is my gradle task:

```
task modifyCommonJsPath(type: Copy) {
    from "functions/generated"
    into "functions"
    include "index.js"
    filter {
        it.replaceAll( "require\\('common-js'\\)", "require('./generated/common-js')" )
    }
}

compileKotlin2Js.finalizedBy modifyCommonJsPath
```

Comment: Actually, your solution helped me with my packages, thanks.